# NotificationHubClient.GetRegistrationsByChannelAsync(deviceToken, 10) gives no results on iOS

Tags: azure, azure-notificationhub

`NotificationHubClient.GetRegistrationsByChannelAsync(deviceToken, 10)` **does not give any results on iOS. It works correctly on Android.** I can see in NotificationHub the device is registered, push notifications also come in correctly but I can't unregister the device for iOS because the registration is not retrieved.

I went through this documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-push-notification-registration-management

The only thing I can see is that the registrationId is saved here so I will try to go this way now, but is this a bug in NotificationHubClient because the code I am looking at hasn't been touched for 4 years.

The only problem with handling registrations by registrationID is that there is no way of retrieving the registrationIDs of devices that are already registered.

**Update:** I tried using the "Manage/Listen/Send" connection string, same result: `GetRegistrationsByChannelAsync` works for Android, it does not work for iOS. If I use `GetRegistrationsByTagAsync`, I get 47 registrations for the same tag, 46 for iOS, 1 for Android, these are all duplicate registrations because I can't delete the existing registration anymore. But I cannot use the `GetRegistrationsByTagAsync` because it requires the "Manage/Listen/Send" connection string, and we can't use that in the app.